# Resize rigidbody in runtime, Box collider OnTriggerEnter not work

Tags: unity, collider

Scene setting:

Object A:
Rigidbody, kinmeatic
Box collider, is trigger true.

Object B:
Box collider, is trigger true.

Script is on Object A:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(increaseScale)
    {
        transform.localScale += transform.forward* speed;

        // when to stop 
        if ((AEForward * transform.localScale.z).sqrMagnitude >= range * range)
            increaseScale = false;
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log(other.transform);
}
```

No log message when part of object A is inside B.

And the funny part is if I use it on a sphere collider, it works. (use                       transform.localScale += new vector3(1,1,1)* speed; instead )

Comment: Have a look at the [collision matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) at the bottom. Double check that your setup will actually work.

Comment: Not physical layer setting problem, because they all in default layer, and the sphere object have no problem.

Comment: The collision matrix isn't related to layers. It's about the colliders and rigidbodies used.

Comment: I'd use an OverlapBox query for this, rather than dynamically scaling a collider.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you need to have a Rigidbody attached to both object A and object B to register a trigger collision. It looks like you only have one attached to object A.

Comment: Your case is OnCollisionEnter().

Comment: @Shitman It's actually not. You *must* have both a collider and a rigidbody attached to both objects in order to detect collisions.

Comment: Are you sure? My scene work on sphere collider.

Comment: @user115399 no, it's sufficient if only one of the objects has a rigidbody, [as shown in the collision action matrix for Trigger messages here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) (see "Rigidbody Collider / Rigidbody Trigger Collider" rows where they intersect the "Static Collider / Static Trigger Collider" columns)